# How do I add a border radius to an image that has clip-path:polygon?

Tags: html, css

I currently have two images placed next to each other with the one on the right being clipped like below.

```
clip-path: polygon(52.5% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,47.5% 100%);
```

How can I add the same border radius to the right image as there is on the left?

The left image has `border-radius:1em` but that does not work on clipped images.

[image: example image]

Comment: [border-radius](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) CSS function should do the trick, otherwise could you please provide full code, HTML and CSS?

Comment: add radius to the container